# How to find the names of the trainable layers in a tensorflow model?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorboard, tensorflow-slim

I am trying to fine tune the last few layers in the [tensorflow/slim resnet-v2-50](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/resnet_v2.py) model for a dataset that I have.

I am struggling to find the names of the layers that I can train. In a tensorflow model, **is there a way to find the names of the layers which are train-able?** Is there a way to get these names an ordered way so that I can select a few last layers to train? Is there a way to get this information from tensorboard?

Comment: This should work `all_train_vars =tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)` . This will display all the variable for each layer which are set to trainable

Answer (score 0):

Just type

```
print(tf.trainable_variables())
```

This will print all the trainable variables.

When you want to train or optimize only certain layers of a pre-trained network, this is what you need to know.

TensorFlow's `minimize` method takes an optional argument `var_list`, a list of variables to be adjusted through back-propagation.

If you don't specify `var_list`, any TF variable in the graph could be adjusted by the optimizer. When you specify some variables in `var_list`, TF holds all other variables constant.

Here's an example of a script which [jonbruner](https://www.reddit.com/user/jonbruner) and his collaborator have used.

```
tvars = tf.trainable_variables()
g_vars = [var for var in tvars if 'g_' in var.name]
g_trainer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0001).minimize(g_loss, var_list=g_vars)
```

This finds all the variables they defined earlier that have "g_" in the variable name, puts them into a list, and runs the ADAM optimizer on them.

You can find the related answers here on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-only-train-the-final-layer-of-a-Neural-Net-in-TensorFlow-that-was-already-trained)